Trigonometry application to battleships
I don't know if this is the right place to ask this question, but I'm having some trouble understanding this application of trigonometry.
So, basically, we're constructing two right triangles in which the trajectory of an artillery shell plays the role of the hypothenuse and the thickness of the deck's or the belt's armor of a battleship play the role of one of the sides of the triangle (see image attached below).

We're assuming that artillery shells have a constant penetration ability of 400 mm and, according to the activity where I got this from and my instructor, if the thickness of the armor is greater than the penetrative ability of the artillery shell, it will not cause critical damage.
Solving for the triangles and doing the trigonometry is not the problem at all (for example, if $\theta = 7^{\circ}$, then the value of the hypothenuse for the triangle with $b = 343$ mm is (approximately) 345.67 mm and the value of the hypothenuse for the triangle with $d = 80$ mm is (approximately) 656.44 mm), but actually understanding the context of the problem is what is causing me a lot of trouble.
So, from what I understand if the hypothenuse of the triangle (which is how far the artillery shell travels) is greater than the thickness of the deck's or belt's armor, it will cause critical damage, but this would always be the case since both of these thicknesses would be modeled by one of the sides of the right triangles we're considering and the hypothenuse would always be greater than any of these two sides. Therefore, there must be something that I'm misunderstanding and, for instance, for $\theta = 7^{\circ}$, since 656.44 is greater than the penetration ability of the shell (400), does that mean that the shell would cause damage if it strikes the deck and since 345.67 is lower than 400, does that mean that the battleship would survive if it strikes the belt or is it the other way around or am I completely lost on my understanding of this application of trigonometry?
Also, how could I approach a question like what would be the minimum thickness needed for the deck and belt armor in order for the battleship to survive if we can guarantee that $\theta \geq 7^{\circ}$ and same question if we cannot guarantee that $\theta \geq 7^{\circ}$ (don't know how to even approach these questions since I'm not even understanding the context of the problem)?
Any help or insight would be very much appreciated.

The aim is to find a critical angle $\theta^$ for which all $0\leq |\theta| < \theta^$ will cause critical damage. If the thickness of the wall is $t$ (in your case, either 80mm or 343mm), and the critical thickness to prevent damage is $t^>t$ (in your case, 400mm), then $\theta^=\cos^{-1}(t/t^)$. You can easily invert this equation to find a minimum thickness $t$ for given $\theta^$.

It's a bit unclear what the source of the confusion is, so let's give a detailed explanation, from the top down.
In the big picture, we are firing shells at an armoured battleship. The ship has a band of armour around its sides, called the belt armour. It also has a thinner layer of armour, the deck, presumably protecting the other sides of the ship. Any effective shot on the battleship will require the shell to travel through one of the layers of armour to hit the ship. The question is, which layers of armour will be effective?
We know that the shells can travel a fixed distance ($400\mathrm{mm}$) through armour, before the armour stops it. A shell that stops inside the armour this way is not an effective hit, as the armour has prevented the shell from piercing to the more delicate insides of the ship. So, we want there to be less than $400\mathrm{mm}$ of armour in the path of our shells.
To make this determination, we can choose where to aim our shots. Do we aim for the side, and hit the belt armour? Or do we aim for the rear of the ship and hit the deck armour (I am assuming this is where the deck armour lies)?
Here's an illustration of the scenario:

We are facing the back-right corner of ship, firing shells at a fixed angle (or roughly fixed, since we are a significant distance away). From this angle, will the shell travel through more armour going through the belt? Or through the deck? Maybe, from this angle, both paths include at least $400\mathrm{mm}$ of armour, and neither shot is viable. Or maybe both are viable.
To figure out if a shot is viable, we need to figure out how much armour lies in the path of the shell. This involves two separate calculations, both for the belt and the deck. To illustrate, let's concentrate on the deck. In either case, we need to know the thickness of the armour ($343\mathrm{mm}$), how much armour the shell can puncture ($400\mathrm{mm}$), and the angle from which we are firing. We get a picture like this:

The lines are possible trajectories for the shell. The red line segments represents $400\mathrm{mm}$ (not to scale). If the red line segment comes out of the other side (as with $\theta_2$), then it's a good hit: the shell passed through the belt. If the red line doesn't make it through the armour (as with $\theta_1$), then the shell doesn't continue (and neither does the line marking its trajectory). The shell is stopped by the armour, and the damage is not significant.
The shells and red line segments follows the hypotenuse of these triangles, with adjacent side $343\mathrm{mm}$. So, we are essentially asking, is the hypotenuse, from this angle, greater than or less than $400\mathrm{mm}$? If greater, a good hit. If lesser, a bad hit.
Bad hits when the angle between the armour surface and the shell's trajectory is too shallow (i.e. $\theta$ gets close to $90^\circ$). Good hits occur when the shell travels more perpendicularly to the surface of the armour (i.e. $\theta$ is close to $0^\circ$).
Because the deck is (assumedly) perpendicular to the belt, the angle $\theta$ in the above diagram will be complementary to the corresponding angle for the deck shot, i.e. the sum of the two angles is $90^\circ$. For example, if the ship is essentially side-on to you, and you fire at the belt with an angle of $\theta = 7^\circ$, you'll be in a good position to puncture the belt armour. However, with such a shot, your shot's trajectory will be almost parallel to the deck, coming in at an angle of $83^\circ$, meaning the shell will essentially graze the deck armour without puncturing it. The better angle for shooting one strip of armour, the worse the angle will be to shoot the other strip of armour.
So, in your example, where the shell travels about $346\mathrm{mm}$, the battleship is damaged critically. It does not "survive". It's a good shot. If you consider the angle, say, $35^\circ$ and fire at the belt, you'll find that the hypotenuse is about $419\mathrm{mm}$, meaning that the shell gets lodged in the armour about $19\mathrm{mm}$ away from the ship's innards, meaning the ship will "survive" the shot.
So, from which angles could we make a successful attack on the belt? Note that, for a shot to be successful, we require the hypotenuse to be at least $400\mathrm{mm}$ long. We can compute the hypotenuse in terms of an unknown angle $\theta$:
$$\cos \theta = \frac{\mathrm{adj}}{\mathrm{hyp}} = \frac{343}{\mathrm{hyp}},$$
so
$$\mathrm{hyp} \cos \theta = 343,$$
and so
$$\mathrm{hyp} = \frac{343}{\cos \theta}.$$
A good shot happens when $\mathrm{hyp} \le 400$, so
$$\frac{343}{\cos \theta} \le 400.$$
We can assume $\theta$ lies between $0$ and $90^\circ$, otherwise our shot is going to be parallel to, or even away from, the ship, and so $\cos \theta > 0$. Because $\cos \theta$ is positive, we can multiply both sides by $\cos \theta$ without changing the $\le$ sign:
$$343 \le 400 \cos \theta,$$
and so
$$\cos \theta \ge \frac{343}{400} = 0.8575.$$
In other words, so long as $\cos \theta$ is at least this amount, the hit is good. Here is an illustration of the inequality:

The red curve is $y = \sin x^\circ$ and the green line is $y = 0.8575$. We are interested when the red curve lies above the green line, i.e. where $\cos x^\circ \ge 0.8575$. This is highlighted on the $x$ axis below the curve, with the thick orange line segment, which covers all the possible angles that will cause a good hit on the belt.
As you can see from the picture, the orange zone includes $0^\circ$, and goes a little further than $30^\circ$ each side. This validates the idea that smaller angles are better. It shows that $35^\circ$ will not be a good hit (as I calculated), but also that's it's pretty close to being a good hit (the $35^\circ$ angle is sort of close to the approximately $31^\circ$ cut-off).
If we want to know, precisely, what the cut-off for the angle is, we look at the edge case, where $\mathrm{hyp} = 400\mathrm{mm}$, i.e. where $\cos \theta = 0.8575$. This occurs (at least, when $\theta$ is between $0$ and $90^\circ$) at $\cos^{-1}(0.8575)$, which we can use a calculator to tell evaluate to about $30.96^\circ$. That is, if $\theta$ is between $0$ and $30.96^\circ$, it's a good hit. If not, then it's not.

It's also possible to perform a similar analysis on the deck armour, given that the angle of approach will be $90^\circ - \theta$. Let's call this angle $\alpha$. Performing similar calculations, we have
$$\cos \alpha = \frac{80}{\mathrm{hyp}}$$
so
$$\mathrm{hyp} = \frac{80}{\cos \alpha}.$$
Once again, we require $\mathrm{hyp} \le 400$, which leads, similarly, to
$$\cos \alpha \ge \frac{80}{400} = 0.2.$$
As such, we want $\alpha$ to lie between $0$ and $\cos^{-1}(0.2) \approx 78.46^\circ$. Or, if we convert this to being in terms of $\theta$, we want $\theta$ to lie between $90^\circ$ and $90^\circ - 78.46^\circ = 21.54^\circ$. Note that the thinner armour of $80\mathrm{mm}$ means that a wider variety of angles will suffice!
So, in summary:

Between $0^\circ$ and $21.54^\circ$, only a belt shot will be effective.
Between $21.54^\circ$ and $30.96^\circ$, either a belt or deck shot will be effective.
Between $30.96^\circ$ and $90^\circ$, only a deck shot will be effective.

Hope that clears everything up.
